# How to know which apk correspond to a shortcut?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, apk, uninstallation

My Chinese smartphone VIVO S7i has some shortcuts which I want to remove. Those are: LifeHUB, BeautyHUB, MediaHUB, ReadingHUB and GameHUB.

I could remove the shortcuts with a long press on them. Then, tapping on the cross (x) would remove them.

I would like to remove the app thought, not just the shortcuts. I'm using [System App Safe Removal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jumobile.manager.systemapp). Unfortunately, I didn't find which app corresponds to those shortcuts.

---

UPDATE 1:

I also tried openning one of the shorcuts. Then, pushing on the `Home` button. Next, pushing on the `Settings` button. On the menu, tap on Settings - More settings - Applications - Running.

Unfortunately, that application is not in that list, so I guess it is closed when I push on the `Home` button.

Comment: I think the device is rooted. And, have you considered the databases on your launcher app to lead you to know which shortcuts belongs to which apps or launches them? First few lines [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/114096/96277) would give you the idea, although the question is old, so the issue might have been solved by now.

Comment: It was not solved but I got a new phone. Your comment will help to other people in the future thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-Close all apps

-Open the app by clicking on the shortcut

-Navigate to multitasking screen

-This will show the currently cached/running apps

-Locate the app name which corresponds to the app opened by the shortcut

-You have now found the app.

Comment: What do you mean with "Navigate to multitasking screen". Is it related with what I have written at UPDATE 1?