# Where I can find factory home screen layout file?

Tags: screen, file-system, rom, home-screen, system-apps

Where I can find factory  home screen layout file?

I would like modify default layout which will persist after I will make a hard reset.

Best

**Edit**

device: Lenovo A6000, kitkat 4.4.4

rom: orignal stok rom from Lenovo

home screen launcher: LenovoLauncher com.lenovo.xlauncher

Comment: Great, thanks! What I forgot to ask for: the device is rooted, right? Without root, chances are zero, as you will have to modify "system stuff" (most likely the `.apk` file of the launcher residing in `/system/app` – but that part I better leave to those with better expertise than I have).

Comment: @Izzy so default layout is hardcoded into .apk??? yes I 'm root

Comment: It's not exactly my area of expertise (I'm not a dev), but that's the only place making sense to me, for several reasons: 1) launchers are replaceable, so while possible it doesn't make much sense to spread the information across the system; 2) on init, `/data/data/<package_name>` will be created – but a factory reset will remove that again. So where shall it come from? A launcher is a "regular app", even if installed as system app. I wouldn't want that to "mingle" with other OS components.

Comment: @Izzy Good pointer! I extended the theory based on it with a bit of backing from here and there in my answer.-

Comment: Well done, @Firelord (+1 on both ends). That said, we're going "border-line" now – so, lobi, asking how to change that would most likely go beyond this site's scope – unless you only intend to re-populate that database, which should count as power-user part. Though I rather guess with knowing where it is, you're able to figure the rest :)

Answer (score 4):

Izzy opined it correctly [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/115713/where-i-can-find-factory-home-screen-layout-file#comment143808_115713) that the only sensible place for having factory home screen layout is the launcher's APK itself.

Since I don't own a Lenovo device let alone your specific model I  used my MTK device running stock 4.2.1 as the testing ground. It has stock launcher (`com.android.launcher`).

About that thing called factory home screen layout -- a launcher usually has one or more databases inside its `/data/data/..` directory, and one of that database has a table named `favorites` (name could differ among launchers but the idea is same). (See [my answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/114096/96277) for [How can I manage “desktop” icons](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/66897/96277) to know what I'm talking about.)

The default setting that you see is nothing but code in the APK creating  database(s) from scratch and populating the `favorites` table with hard-coded entries (like "Contacts", "Phone", "Messages", "Chrome" at the dock).

E.g. See this code snippet from the source code of `com.android.launcher`:

[image]

The code is available [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher/+/master/src/com/android/launcher/LauncherProvider.java). If you look closely at few lines above the line 262, you would see that the code is creating a new database with proper schema and then populating the database with `favorites` table which is available to it.

At this point, I didn't bother digging more to know, where does this `favorites` table or the related content is saved, since my conclusion is drawn from custom launchers as well who also have a different but a factory layout (clearly not saved outside the APK).

I would recommend taking a look at the source code (provided that you can find it first) of your default launcher, or extract the APK and dig under `res` folder. I found some interesting stuff under `res/xml/`.

---

Oh, if someone wants to experiment on OP's question then I suggest you do **Clear Data** from **Settings → Apps → All apps → `<Your Launcher>`** since it would have the same effect as doing a [factory reset (not Hard reset)](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/hard-reset/info).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried to decompile Lenovo Launcher.apk, but problem is that when I recompile it, it stop working properly. When I decompile it. I found this assets/profile/app_config.xml http://paste.ubuntu.com/11913136/
I decopile and recompile with apktool and with apkstudio which is GUI for apktool.

Comment: Sorry lobi, I'm not really familiar with decompiling and recompiling  of APKs. Can't be of any help here. May be you can try posting a new question in that regard.