# Where is the layout file for the Sony Xperia launcher?

Tags: sony-xperia, home-screen

Due to unrelated reasons my homescreen may reset sometimes. I do not seek help with that, and in fact I am already sure it cannot be fixed right now. However it is annoying to put everything back all the time.

So here's my idea: to work around this, I need to make a backup of the layout file whenever I change it, and when it resets, restore the backup. This way, I won't have to put everything back myself, just restore the file, restart the launcher, and everything is back to normal.

However, I cannot find this file. Where is it?

Comment: [tag:backup] your launcher app. That's where your custom layout is. Most likely stored in a database. Related: [Where I can find factory home screen layout file?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/115713)

Comment: I couldn't backup system apps using the stock backup app, but I found it. Thanks for pointing me at database files.

Answer (score 1):

You will need root permission to do this.

The files for the stock launcher are in /data/data/com.sonyericsson.home/databases. You need to back up the database AND the journal. If it ever resets, just restore the files. After that, you need to restart the launcher for the backup to take effect. You can do this by temporarily switching launchers and then going back. You could also do this by using a task killer (note - there is no need to have a task killer, refer [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/127388/htg-explains-why-you-shouldnt-use-a-task-killer-on-android/))

Note that the location for the layout file is almost always in /data/data/<app package>/database. <app package> usually looks like com.company.launcher.